# Ubuntu NVIDIA graphical bug/corruption after waking from suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, suspend

After waking up from suspend, graphics look like on the [image: Screenshot].
Ubuntu version: 20.04 
Driver: nvidia-driver-450 
Graphics card: NVIDIA Quadro P1000 
Laptop: Lenovo P52

Comment: @N0rbert fixed omg, how did i not think of googling "chrome", hehe. I'm using an electron app which has the same graphics bug... no way to access "chrome" options there.